# Opening Password Protected File in C# without removing password protection

Tags: c#, pdf, password-protection

Good day, I am currently working on a project regarding PDF file viewing via LAN, unfortunately, I am stuck with the dilemma of having an unsecured pdf file in the server or secured and have the users type the password every time.

Is it possible to have the password written before Filestream(pathfile, FileMode.Open) runs and when they "download" it, the file still has the password required field? I know how to use itextsharp creates copy and when you download the file in browsers, the file no longer has the password needed.

Thanks in advance and happy coding!

Comment: you could have them download a unencrypted version of the file after writing a password to unlock and initiate the download. a encrypted file with lets say no password is just as good as an unencrypted file.

Comment: @ThomasAndreèLian

Thank you for your quick reply, and the answer is greatly appreciated. Although the users will have the option to view the file, and since (your suggestion) its unencrypted, they can download it without encryption, if left in an unsafe computer, the file can be seen by other people, that's the issue I'm quite unsure how to address. Our clients are quite lazy that they need to input password every time they view the file via web browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to be able to open the file without entering the password, that would be the same level of security as unencrypted. If its encrypted you need to decrypt it every time it is opened (no ways around that).

Think of it this way, the file is encrypted on your server, they download it and enter the password, decrypt and open it. If it is in a browser the encrypted file is still downloaded and stored in a temporary folder and opened in the browser. if you store the password for esay opening of the file. The file will need it in plain text, meaning that it's stored on the machine along with the pdf -> not secure either.

There is a possible solution that might be usable, but not as secure. You could look into PDF.js it is a pdf renderer in js. it have support for some decryption (possibly not all)
Then you could possibly store the password in a similar fashion as with website logins, at least you could hijack the password control and decrypt it for them without the prompt. (they actually store passwords in plain text just so you are informed, most if not all browser passwords can be stolen easily).